# Why was this question closed as off-topic for "seeking recommendations or open-ended lists"?

Tags: discussion

This question was closed for "seeking recommendations or open-ended lists", neither of which are true. There is definitely a limit to the depictions asked for, and no recommendation was asked for.

- [Which species did Tolkien show to laugh or cry?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/278309/which-species-did-tolkien-show-to-laugh-or-cry)

[image]

While I understand that some didn't like the question, that doesn't mean it's off-topic. It was even commented that it was interesting to ask.

I note that there was [a similar question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/278240/which-species-dance-in-tolkiens-works) recently on which species danced, which was upvoted and kept.

Comment: The title of this post is off-putting, especially for the users who voted to close your question. I suggest you re-phrase it to *ask* something like "how can I improve my question to get it re-opened?" That would allow users to answer with suggestions to improve it or say that they think it is fine as-is.

Comment: Yes closing it for reasons not valid is off-putting.

Comment: The first question was very specific - of a finite number of depicted races, which were shown to dance. The new question is more vague - there are a lot of emotions, and feeling them is not necessarily the same as showing them.

Comment: @Michael - Even that got bogged down in an extensive discussion of what constitutes 'dancing'.

Comment: "It was even commented that it was interesting to ask." Might be redundant to point this out now that OP has apparently deleted their account, but I don't see any comments on the original question saying anything like this, so either the comment was deleted or OP was mistaken.

Answer (score 3):

This question should not have been closed for seeking recommendations or open-ended lists. As you've said, there are only a limited number of works that can be consulted (approx 15, depending on what you consider to be part of "Tolkien's Legendarium") and you're certainly not looking for recommendations.

That being said, your question (as asked) was very widely scoped and basically unanswerable.

> "I'm wondering about the emotional range shown for each species"

is a very messy title and your subsequent edits didn't really get to the bottom of what you were actually asking. **This question should rightly have been closed for *lacking focus*, not being a list question.**

Comment: There's also the fact that one question about "*whether and which species do x*" is moderately interesting, but a second and third and fourth question might get really old, really quickly.

Comment: Which might be cause to ignore or downvote, but wouldn't make it off topic.

Comment: @Michael - Indeed. We should undelete it, reopen it and then immediate reclose it for the correct reason. We can then downvote it and eventually it'll get deleted.

Comment: Referring to your first comment rather than your answer - agree with the latter, certainly for the question as first written. A series of similar questions would indeed get old and less interesting, but that wouldn't be a reason to close.

Comment: @Michael - Indeed. The answer above is an attempt to educate our close-voters to use the right close-reason rather than a serious attempt to get this reopened. I think they instinctively knew that the question needed closing, but struggled to articulate that when they chose the reason.

Comment: How's that not a list based question? "_Which species are depicted as doing something_" almost automatically makes a complete answer require a list to be fully complete. If the list is finite then surely the species asked about should be defined? Each species meaning Elves, Dwarves, Hobbits, Men, Cows, Rabbits,...? Where does it end? So therefore, closing as either list based or lacking focus makes sense here

Comment: @fez - We accept lists that are closed and finite. "*Which species in Trek have gills?*" is a pretty small list, for example, despite there being thousands of *possible* matches.

Comment: Finite, _well scoped_ lists yes, the question was not scoped very well at all.

Comment: @fez - I'd still argue that this question was poorly scoped rather than being a 'list question'